# Suitable Rpi model and camera module?

Tags: camera, image, pi-models

I wanna ask... If my project is focused on a camera monitoring surveillance system that is mainly to detect images of small animals like rats especially at night in paddy fields area, can you suggest me suitable Raspberry pi board and camera module?

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're referring to seeing animals at **night** - that appears you are implying you need an Infrared (IR) module.

I found this particular one here:  [Raspberry Pi Cameras List](https://www.electromaker.io/blog/article/best-raspberry-pi-cameras)

Specifically:

> The Raspberry Pi Infrared Camera Module includes a normal lens along with two IR modules. **It's compatible with the Raspberry Pi 1, 2, 3, and 4.** An onboard 5MP OV5647 sensor captures good images. There's a 3.6MM adjustable focal length and a 1.8F aperture. Able to capture 1080p at its highest resolution, the Raspberry Pi Infrared Camera Module is a budget-priced IR camera. Unfortunately, the 5-megapixel sensor is a bit on the low side, though images and videos still come out looking good.
>
> Pros:
>
> IR camera Compatible with every version of the Raspberry Pi 5MP OV5647
> sensor
> 3.6MM adjustable focal length
> 1.8F aperture 1080p max resolution Affordable Cons:
>
> Cons:
>
> Not suitable for daytime photography and video

Therefore, to answer your question:  As stated above, **"It's compatible with the Raspberry Pi 1, 2, 3, and 4."** I don't know your budget, but this is the video particular camera module in question which should suffice what you're trying to do:  [Raspbrry Pi Infrared Camera Module](https://www.electromaker.io/shop/product/raspbrry-pi-infrared-camera-module)

Answer (score 0):

I use a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with the night vision camera module, both sold by the official company. The parts do a great job. Records on movement, Records great at night. I bought it for around 10 bucks, bought the pi for 25  bucks. Not sure how much it is now. I use an 8 gig card with uploading, plenty of room for OpenCV projects , can control remotely. not the greatest hardening but does the trick. Also I know this could be off topic but I managed to get equal or greater quality and same effects and monitoring from repurposing old cellphones.